# Is it secure to store ad-unit id in my swift code?

Tags: swift, admob

After reading many posts about admob suspension, and how easy it is to get the ban-hammer for android developers, is it safe to store my admob unit-id as a string variable within my code? I assume iOS is safe enough to prevent these.

`let ad_string = ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716 (test ad)`

I read posts about developers hiring people in china to auto-click people's ad banner for admob suspension and to take down competitors, which made me feel unease about monetizing my apps. What are ways to midigate the risks in swift?

Comment: Um... if that is your token/key (I'm not familiar with admob), then you probobly shouldn't post it publicly here.

Comment: Its a test ad, forgot to mention

Comment: Clicking on Test Ads is perfectly fine. You can store it anywhere. As for the click-hammer, well that is a very broad topic. You can always reach out to AdMob support for letting them know of unusual activity / clicks if you detect that your CTR is rising sharply in a small period of time.

Comment: Have you implemented some protective measures, like click delay?  each time an ad is clicked, disable clicks for 30 seconds. Have you had any issues with admob by simply having the unit string in your source code?